# How do I response "accept (minor edits)" without suggestions? (IEEE ACCESS)

Tags: publications, peer-review

I just received a decision letter from IEEE ACCESS. The recommendation of reviewer1 is "Accept (minor edits)" and the recommendation of reviewer2 is "Reject (update and resubmit encouraged)".

While reviewer1 did not give any suggestions need to be revised. Did I need to respond to him in the "response document"?

Thank you.

Comment: What did the editor say the final decision was? Contact the editor if you are still confused.

Comment: If the reviewer does not ask to do anything, say ‘we greatly appreciate the reviewer’s effort to carefully review the paper in the earlier round’.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you for your reply. The finial decision is "We do encourage you to revise and resubmit your article once you have addressed the concerns and criticisms of the reviewers." and I plan to resubmit the paper after revision.

Comment: @Mithun Your help is much appreciated, and maybe I would also add some contents about what I had revised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the first reviewer was referring to minor issues of language and presentation, even spelling, typos, etc. Give the paper a careful read looking for issues and correct them. If you do this, it is unlikely that you really need a direct response to that reviewer, other than thanks. Many reviewers don't want to take on the role of "copy editors" and so will just point to that things can be improved without giving detail.

If your first language is other than the language of the paper, then it might be good to have a colleague make some comments on presentation - someone who is fluent in the language in question.

The other reviewer needs to be taken seriously, of course, and your acceptance will depend on how you respond, primarily in your edits of the paper. But that is the usual situation, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Congratulations! it means your article was accepted. If there were any comments from the reviewers, you need to incorporate them before uploading final files. Otherwise, review one more time for grammar and spelling and then upload your final version of the article.

Comment: The "accept" was a recommendation from a reviewer, not a decision from the editor. The paper has almost certainly not yet been accepted.

Comment: I think this is too optimistic. Though I really hope the paper could be accepted, I think I should revise the paper carefully.